# javascript load other script - call function - undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var aaascript = document.createElement('script'); aaascript.type = 'text/javascript';
aaascript.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://xxx' : 'http://xxx') + '/aaa.js';
var aaas = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; aaas.parentNode.insertBefore(aaascript,aaas);
callthis('somevalue');
</script>
```

this code generates a script tag and inserts it to the page. in the script aaa.js is the function callthis. but when I call the function there is this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callthis is not defined (anonymous function)
```

what goes wrong here?

Comment: Most probably due to the fact that you are loading it at runtime via javascript it is not being parsed ergo you do not have the methods available. Needs some testing though. Are you receiving any errors whatsoever or are there any variables in there that are available? Consider using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261408/good-practice-method-for-loading-javascript-via-ajax instead if possible.

Comment: no there are no other errors. I cant use jquery in this case, need plain js

Comment: Simon has a point, that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I realise you're not after a jQuery solution but for others' reference: the `getscript` or `ajax` methods Alex linked to can be used to load the script. Using your example, you would still need to delay calling `callthis()` until the script is loaded, by wrapping it in a function and putting it in the `success` parameter of those jQuery methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `script` tag is being created but the script is then loaded from the server. `callthis()` is being called in between these two events; that is, before the script is fully loaded, and so the method doesn't exist.

Use the `.onload` event of the script tag to delay calling `callthis()` until the script is fully loaded, as documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).